# SSIS Variables Not Updating When Execute Package on Server

Tags: variables, deployment, ssis

I have created a package that does the following:

1. ExecuteSQLTask: queries db table and sets package variables from data returned
2. DataFlowTask starts
3. OleDBSource: uses package variables as parameters to call stored procedure
4. FlatFileDestination: uses package variables to save a tab delimited file in the correct location and filename
5. SendEmailTask: uses package variables to email the file as attachment to recipient

I have the following vars:

- FileName
- sp_Param1
- sp_param2
- emailRecipient
- SMTPServer

At design time, each var has dummy values.  When I run the package in VS, it works perfectly.  I can update the values in the db table and each execution picks up the new values and works.

The problem begins when I deploy the package to the database and execute it.  It appears to not be setting the variables from the db table any longer and it uses the dummy data that I used during design time.  What is going on?

Comment: Do you have proper error tracking to ensure that the steps are not failing that are setting the variables?  When running from the server does the ID running the package have correct access to the tables to obtain the variables?

Comment: Smells like the ExecuteSQLTask isn't finding the data. Are you perhaps pointing to a different table when it runs in the server environment? Also, can you verify the deployed package is the same as the one you're running via Visual Studio? Finally, how are you executing the package on the server?